# Cannot change my python language from python 2 to python3 in vscode code-runner.executorMap

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I tried to change the settings of code runner-executorMap-edit in `settings.json`, it did't show the code in settings.json, it only shows the modified settings.

[image]

And when I copy settings as JSON, and paste in the settings.json, there is an error "code-runner.executorMap" and says `End of file expected`. I cannot save any changes with this error.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem!

Comment: Check this https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/366

Comment: tried that, did't work...